# While loops not printing out first form iteration but printing out other first contents?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm echoing a bunch of forms within a while loop(reading out from a database).

But for some reason it doesn't print out the first form but it prints out the first contents and in the rest of the loop it prints the rest of the form and it contents
PHP code

```
$edit = db::run_query("
    SELECT
    feature_name, id
    FROM
    `sp_itemsa_features`
    Where 
    `id` = '556'

",db::return_rows);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($edit)) {


    echo'<form class="feature-box" >
<ul>
    <li><span>Feature Name</span>  "'.$row['feature_name'].'"  </li>';

    $query2  = " 
    SELECT product_id, id FROM sp_itemsa_features_items
    WHERE feature_id = '".$row['id']."'
    ";

    $pids = db::run_query($query2,db::return_rows);

   while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($pids)){

 echo '<form class = "test" method = "POST">
 <li><span>Remote ID</span> <input type = "text" name = "pid" value = "'.$row2['product_id'].'">  </li>
<li><input type="hidden" name="editId" value="'.$row2['id'].'" /></li>
<li><input type="submit" class="submitbtn" name="editsubmit" value="submit edit" /></li></form>';

}
echo '</ul></form>';
}
```

note all the DB run_query stuff it part of a database class they just connect and query from the database

Comment: You have `"Where"` instead of `"WHERE"` on your first query.

Comment: @philtune does it change something?

Comment: Noted... just saw that hanging out there. I might have OCD, but my mother never had me tested.

Comment: Why are you trying to nest a form inside another form?

Comment: yeah it was the designer idea to nest this to make it look like a certain way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is also invalid:

```
<ul>
   <li>...</li>
   <form ...>   <--- not valid
```

a `<ul>` and `<ol>` can have have only other lists, `<li>` or `<col>` elements as descendants.

Plus, you're embedding forms-in-forms. That is not permitted:

```
<form><form>...</form></form>   <-- illegal html
```

And largest of all, since you're getting PHP code as part of the output, you really should look at your browser's "view source". It's possible the ENTIRE script is not executing, and you're simply getting all of the PHP code. The `<?php ... ?>` blocks would be interpreted as illegal/unknown html tags and simply not rendered.